# C: Last element in char* array rewriting all array entries

Tags: c, arrays, string, fgets

I need to load a series of single-word lines from a file into an array, so I made a function to do so. The function takes `char*** arr` as a parameter, which is a pointer to the array of strings. I allocate memory then have this loop to load words into the array.

```
i=0;
FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
while(fgets(tok, WORD_BUFFER, fp) != NULL){
  (*arr)[i] = tok;
  printf("Word %d:%s", i, (*dict)[i]);
  i++;
}
//arr is a char***, tok is a char[WORD_BUFFER], and WORD_BUFFER is 50
```

My problem is that this seems to be overwriting every entry of the array with whatever I'm trying to enter to entry [i]. I say this because the output of the loop above for a file that looks something like this:

```
A
B
C
D
```

Seems to print correctly, however when I print the array in the main function (or even just later in that function), it will print out like:

```
D
D
D
D
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with my use of `fgets` or the assignment of `(*arr)[i] = tok` but I'm not sure.
Thanks!

Comment: After this statement (*arr)[i] = tok ; all elements of the array has the same value of the variable tok,

Comment: Why is that? Why wouldn't it only make arr[i] have the value of tok?

Comment: you're just doing a pointer assignment with the `=` operator. `tok` gets overwritten with what's in file every iteration through the loop. So everything points to `tok`, which is the last line read from the file. You'll need to [`strcpy`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) the data from `tok` to a different destination each time through the loop if you want to save it.

Comment: @yano thank you! Using strcpy worked. I'm a bit confused as to why a simple pointer assignment didn't work as I believe I've done that on some of my previous work with no problem, but nevertheless, thanks a lot!

Comment: of course `arr` must have enough space to store the data, if it does not you invoke undefined behavior when you `strcpy` and write into memory you don't own. This can manifest as a segfault

Answer (score 0):

In light of your comment, I will try to explain what you're doing using a simple `char*` array.  Let's say you have the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  int i;
  char tok[50] = "applesauce";  // tok can contain up to 49 chars plus the NUL terminator

  char* myCharPtr[20];  // this is an array 20 long where each element is of type char*

  // All the loop does is store the _address_ of tok at each position in the
  // myCharPtr array.  The _data_ "applesauce" only exists _once_ in memory,
  // and whatever that address is now fills the contents of myCharPtr.
  // (technically, "applesauce" exists twice in memory, the string literal
  // and the char array.. but neither of those places are in myCharPtr)
  for (i=0; i<20; i++)
  {
    myCharPtr[i] = tok;
  }

  for (i=0; i<20; i++)
  {
    printf("myCharPtr[%d] = %s\n", i, myCharPtr[i]);
    // prints out "applesauce" for each entry because each entry points to tok.
  }

  // Now let's do

  strcpy(tok, "apples");  // "apples" is smaller than 49, so we aren't overwriting the bounds of the array

  for (i=0; i<20; i++)
  {
    printf("myCharPtr[%d] = %s\n", i, myCharPtr[i]);
    // prints out "apples" for each entry because the _pointer_ to tok
    // hasn't changed, but the _data_ in tok has changed.
  }

  // To further re-enforce this, you can do
  printf("address of tok = %p\n", (void*)tok);
  for (i=0; i<20; i++)
  {
    printf("address of myCharPtr[%d] = %p\n", i, (void*)(&myCharPtr[i]));
  }
  // the address for tok will match all the addresses in myCharPtr

  // if you want to actually save/copy the data in tok, then you need to do
  // something like this

  char wordList[20][50];  // this can store up to 20 words that are each up
                          // to 49 chars each (must leave 1 byte for NUL termination
  for (i=0; i<20; i++)
  {
    // assume this function populates tok with new data each call, much like fgets
    // this function would have to ensure it's not writing strings bigger than 49 to tok
    GetNewContentForTok(tok);
    strcpy(wordList[i], tok);
    // now, we are saving the contents of tok each time, not simply copying
    // its pointer.
  }

  for (i=0; i<20; i++)
  {
    printf("wordList[%d] = %s\n", i, wordList[i]);
    // this will print all the strings that were once stored in tok from the previous loop
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I generally try to avoid dealing with `char***` types, as that much indirection can get confusing to me.  I used arrays in my example above, but the same principles would apply to pointers pointing to dynamically allocated memory.